# No qualifying bean of type when using @ConditionalOnProperty

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a component that I what to be able to enable/disable from the applikation.properties in  my spring boot application..

In my application.properties I have

```
wiki.enabled=false
```

And in component looks like this

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty("wiki.enabled")
public class WikiClient {
...
}
```

And finally in my other class where I use the wikiclient I have autowired it like this in my constructor.

```
    @Autowired(required = false)
    public MigrationManager(UserService userService, WikiClient wikiClient) {
    ...
    }
```

Still I get the exception

```
No qualifying bean of type com.test.WikiClient
```

If I enable the property it works like if I enabled the component.

Comment: Well that is what you told it do to with `@ConditionalOnProperty`... It check if `wiki.enabled` is there, with a certain value (default empty) which if not explicitly defined must not be `false`. (As explained in the javadoc of [@ConditionalOnProperty](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html).

Comment: But should not @Autowired(required = false) ignore that the bean does not exists and set it to null?

Comment: Not sure... If that actually works on a constructor. Also I wouldn't put optional dependencies in the constructor but as properties instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by moving the the wikiClient argument to a property and used @Autowired(required = false) instead of having it in the constructor. Like M. Deinum said in the comments. Optional dependencies should not be in the constructor.

Comment: You can also make the constructor parameter an `Optional`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135102/how-to-set-autowired-constructor-params-as-required-false-individually

Answer (score 0):

In your main springboot application class add Annotation @ComponentScan and make sure the package in which WikiClient is defined is included in the ComponentScan.