# How to handle an error when a bean does not exist and could not inject in Spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a standard rest-api spring-boot application.

Controller with injected service

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeController {

    private final SomeService someService;
    
    public void someMethod(){
         someService.toDoSomething();
    }

}
```

and service with injected other beans

```
@Setter
public class SomeService {
    private AnotherVeryImportantBean anotherVeryImportantBean;
    private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplate;

    public void toDoSomething() {
         anotherVeryImportantBean.someAction();
    }
```

In my case, the bean AnotherVeryImportantBean is created in another dependency, which I connect to the spring-boot application. Whether to create a bean or not is decided by a variable in the application.yml file.

like this:

```
another.service.enabled: true
```

Of course I have config class for service

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeConfig {
    private final AnotherVeryImportantBean anotherVeryImportantBean;

    @Bean
    public SomeService someService(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplate) {
         SomeService foo = new SomeService();
         foo.setAnotherVeryImportantBean(anotherVeryImportantBean);
         foo.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
         return foo;
    }
```

The problem is that this controller and service are not the only ones in the application. I would like the application not to crash completely if this particular controller and service are not formed. If the bean is not created for some reason, I just don't use that functionality (this controller).

At this point, the application crashes because AnotherService cannot be injected into someService (In case where, for some reason, it was not created).

I tried adding an annotation to config class

@ConditionalOnBean(AnotherVeryImportantBean.class)

like this:

```
@ConditionalOnBean(AnotherVeryImportantBean.class)
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeConfig {
    private AnotherVeryImportantBean anotherVeryImportantBean;

    @Bean
    public SomeService someService(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplate) {
         SomeService foo = new SomeService();
         foo.setAnotherVeryImportantBean(anotherVeryImportantBean);
         foo.setRestTemplate(restTemplate);
         return foo;
    }
```

But the problem is that conditional in SomeConfig checks if the bean is in the container before it is created.

How can I handle an error when a bean cannot inject another dependency into itself?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135102/how-to-set-autowired-constructor-params-as-required-false-individually

Comment: Have you taken a look at `ConditionalOnProperty` ? You'd add this to all the beans that you only want present if the `another.service.enabled` property is present in your yml.